# WebResourceResponse cause ClassNotFoundException ignoring @TargetApi clause

Tags: java, android, caching, service, webview

I have a simple piece of code:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) return null;
        ...
                try {
                    File input = new File(fullPathToCachedFile);
                    if ( input.exists() == false ) return null;

                    final BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(input));
                    return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, "UTF-8", stream);
                }
                catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        ...

        return null;
    }
```

and this line makes me angry:

```
return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, "UTF-8", stream);
```

On Android 4.4 (for example) whole project works well, but I tried it on Android 2.2 and 2.3.. then console says that doesn't know "WebResourceResponse" class.

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))    
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    PathClassLoader.findClass(String) line: 243 
    PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 573   
    PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 532    
    WebViewExt.defaultConfig() line: 52 (here is about to use WebResourceResponse)
    WebViewExt.init(ForegroundService) line: 35 
    ForegroundService.startWebView(WebViewExt) line: 88 
    MyApplication$1.onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder) line: 78 
    ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(ComponentName, IBinder) line: 1247 
    ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run() line: 1264 
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Why I know, that it is about "WebResourceResponse" class? Without mentioned line project runs well:

```
/*return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, "UTF-8", stream);*/
```

Without it project runs well, without errors and exceptions.

@TargetAPI shouldn't blocks visibility of this "WebResourceResponse" Class for Android? How it works and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it somehow. But it's strange fix. The if statement

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) return null;
```

doesn't work inside shouldInterceptRequest function, but works outside setting WebViewClient custom class:

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB )
    setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientExt2(this)); //with shouldInterceptRequest 
else
    setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientExt(this)); //without
```